# Unable to run liquibase via cmd

Tags: liquibase

I am using DB2 V10.5 (windows), trying to experiment with Liquibase.

I am using liquibase-3.5.3-bin . I have set the liquibase.properties file with following parameters.

```
classpath=lib/db2jcc.jar
changeLogFile=liquibase-3.5.3-bin/003_changelog.xml
username=random_auth
password=random
url=jdbc:db2://host/dbname
driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

I am unable to set the classpath using  multiple jars .So when i run

```
java -jar liquibase.jar generateChangeLog
```

I get the error missing snakeyaml jar

Options I tried for classpath:

```
lib/*
lib/db2jcc.jar:lib/snakeyaml-1.17.jar
```

but somehow it is not working.

Could someone suggest how can I set the classpath so that all the jars present in lib are included, when I run Liquibase.

Answer (score 1):

The path separator in Windows is a `;` not a `:`

So your `liquibase.properties` should look like this:

```
classpath=lib\db2jcc.jar;lib\snakeyaml-1.17.jar
```

That requires that `lib` is a sub-directory of the current directory when you run Liquibase.

---

If those libraries are inside the `lib` directory of the Liquibase directory, then the provided `liquibase.bat` will automatically include all jars in that directory. Just run `liquibase.bat` instead of using `java -jar ...`

Comment: still not working .getting this error  INFO 8/22/18 5:32 PM: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.serializer.core.json.JsonChangeLogSerializer as a Liquibase service because org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer is not in the classpath
INFO 8/22/18 5:32 PM: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.serializer.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogSerializer as a Liquibase service because org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer is not in the classpath
Liquibase 'generateChangeLog' Successful

Comment: liquibase-3.5.3-bin\lib : lib is present in the directory containing the executable jar .Is any change needed in current environment variables , currently i have set only LIQUIBASE_HOME to the root directory .

Comment: If you specify it like that it has to be a sub-directory of the **current** directory, not the one containing the executable. But if you put all jars into `liquibase-3.5.3-bin\lib` then simply run `liquibase.bat` (do not  use `java -jar`) it will automatically include all jars in the `lib` directory.

Comment: One thing you might do is remove the line at the top of `liquibase.bat` that says `@echo off`
This will cause each command that is executed to be shown on the console, giving you an opportunity to get more insight into what is happening. Very useful to know what the actual command being generated is.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. It  is running fine with liquibase.bat .